# Git Workflow Suggestion - To Meet My Needs

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, continuous-integration

I have gone through many links about git branching and agile integrations, With the knowledge, I gathered, I know what I need but need help with How to achieve that.

My Requirement is:

1. One Branch / Issue (or) Feature
2. Two release a month ( in future One release a month ) - Team may be working on more than one release branch parallelly?.

   - I could go with many release branches branched off from Master, and committing one feature to one release branch can be merged into the other release branches created after the current release branch. And I can release the branch again into master by merging it back but now look at the next point.
3. The Feature in the release branch may be backed out before the release. So I should have the flexibility of deciding what should be released. Rather the all merged into one branch?

   - I thought about having an integration branch so all the planned fixes or features can be merged together later only required Branches can be merged with Master. But we are following only manual testing ( don't have CI with automated testing ) at integration branch, So with this, approach I would need to create two test setup, one for release and another one for Integration.

Looking for a way to address this and I am practicing different approach in combinations. Looking for Experts advise here.

In addition to all the above, I look for a flexible workflow that would help me adapt SCRUM / KANBAN anytime with out major change ( We may move to KANBAN shortly).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements:

1. Based on your 2# and 3# requirements, you need to have multiple branches since you need to develop features to release parallel. And you have main branch `master`.
2. Develop different features on different branches, so you can release them separately, and merge into `master`.
3. It’s not necessary to use an `integration` branch between feature branches and `master` branch. Merge feature branches into `master` branch, you can use **pull request** to approve and complete merges.  The feature you want to release by `master` branch, you can approve the pull request. Otherwise, you can hung the pull request there since all the feature branches are separate.

To reflect the changes on Kanban board, you can add work items into each commit. And you should update work items status with your project go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. How ever as i said i hv to give the features merged branch for QA testing. During the QA its found out that the usability of particular feature is not clear and requires updates in the business case which will take time to develop. In this case if i wanna remove that specific feature branch out of master ( consider thr hv bn multiple  tim merges happened ) that would give me an unstable master branch !

Comment: Yeah, If feature branches are merge by developers and QA team can't test it immediately after a feature branch is merged, this will caused master branch in a mess if a certain branch is failed test by QA. Is it possible for your team to merge feature branches into master by QA team? Developers create pull request, then merged by QA, even a feature branch is test failed, QA team can reset master branch.

Comment: Thats another good suggestion but we dont hv CI with automated testing in place( ref #3 :( ). We are just started with unit testing. It is a tool being built​ for two years. Covering all unit and integration testing will take atleast couple of months

Comment: In that case, before merging features/issues with master branch, QA team need to approve each and every issues/features. Release feature/issue branch to QA and ask them to validate. Once they approved and finalize the features which u need for the particular release then merge with master branch and give the final build to QA for smoke test.

Comment: @iDroid did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.